# iOS | OpenGLES 2/3 - glMatrixMode alternative

Tags: c++, ios, qt, opengl-es, openscenegraph

I'm moving an application from Windows to iOS. Then I need to convert "OpenGL" in OpenGL ES. In the original application I had glPush/PopAttrib instructions but it doesn't exist in OpenGL ES. Some people talk about an alternative here: http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.7/opengl-hellogl-es/ BUT they're using glMatrixMode which is only available under OpenGL ES 1.1 (not 2 or 3).

So, does someone have an alternative for glMatrixMode in OpenGL ES 2?

To be more accurate: I'm trying to make Qt and OpenSceneGraph contexts work together. And I don't have any control on what is done in the shaders.

Comment: Rewrite it all to shaders

Answer (score 0):

There is no fixed function matrix stack support in OpenGL ES 2.x onwards. If you want a matrix you have to compute the value yourself and upload one raw via `glUniformMatrix*()`.

Exactly what this matrix needs to be and what the "name" of the uniform symbol is depends entirely on your shaders, and how they process the geometry transform. Normally the application will want to concatenate either a model-view and/or a model-view-projection matrix on the CPU to avoid the need to do the computation per vertex.

Many concepts which exists in OpenGL ES 1.x simply don't exist at all in OpenGL ES 2.x (e.g. no fixed function lighting pipeline for fragments), so it's rarely a simple "port" and more of a need to rewrite big chunks of the rendering engine ...